# Turn Timer lengths

Tags: civilization-4

The **turn timer** for **Civilization 4 multiplayer** has a number of options that are defined by descriptive words, such as  "Slow", "Blazing!!!", or "Snail."  These names are necessary since the **amount of time** that is given for turns on any setting is **dynamic** depending on the era of the game - the length gets longer as the game progresses.

**What is the formula for this amount of time?**  How long does each setting give you on any given turn, and how is it calculated?  Additionally, if quick combat is disabled, time is added during each combat - where is this amount controlled?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The turn length is a function of

- Base timer
- Maximum number of units owned by a single civilization
- Maximum number of cities owned by a single civilization

Timer (seconds) = (Base + City Modifier * Max Cities + Unit Modifier * Max Units) / 4

There's also a multiplier for the first turn.

The modifiers for each setting can be found in
`...Civilization 4\Assets\XML\GameInfo\CIV4TurnTimerInfo.xml`
This file doesn't exist in the expansion directories, so I presume they carry over.

Summary of modifiers:

```
          Base    City    Unit    First Turn Multiplier
Static    240     3       1       4
Snail     360     36      12      6
Slow      180     18      6       5
Medium    120     12      4       4
Fast      100     9       3       3
Blazing   80      6       2       2
```

Apparently static is not actually static.

Source:
Function `getMaxTurnLen()` in source code file `CvGame.cpp`

The coefficient of 4 was verified empirically by @marshaul. The only nearby hint of this in the source is a comment stating that turn time provided by user in Pitboss mode is in hours while the code actually multiplied it by 3600 * 4 (3600 seconds in an hour). This probably would also be evident deeper in the engine code.

Comment: Excellent answer!  And yes, static is not what I expected, but I can understand the name - it has very low variance.

Comment: It sure seems like the units are 1/4 second. For instance, on blazing the first turn is 40 seconds (+ a couple units), the second turn is 20 seconds (+ units/cities).

Comment: @marshaul Thanks for pointing that out. Empirical observation wins!